# Reverse for 'create_order' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create_order/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm getting this error when I use

```
path('create_order/<str:pk>/', views.createOrder, name="create_order"),
```

but there is no such error when path is..

```
path('create_order', views.createOrder, name="create_order"),
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('products/', views.products, name='products'),
    path('customer/<str:pk_test>/', views.customer, name="customer"),

    path('create_order/<str:pk>/', views.createOrder, name="create_order"),
    path('update_order/<str:pk>/', views.updateOrder, name="update_order"),
    path('delete_order/<str:pk>/', views.deleteOrder, name="delete_order"),


]
```

**views.py**

```
def createOrder(request, pk):
    OrderFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Customer, Order , fields=('product','status'), extra=9)
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    formset = OrderFormSet(queryset=Order.objects.none(), instance=customer)
    #form = OrderForm(initial={'customer':customer})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print('printing post', request.POST)
        formset = OrderFormSet(request.POST, instance=customer)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'formset': formset}
    #return redirect('accounts/order_form.html', context)
    return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html', context)
```

i also have tried redirect, that's not working the problem is with urls.py.

**customer.html**

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}

{% block content %}

<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h5>Customer:</h5>
            <hr>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm btn-block" href="">Update Customer</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'create_order' customer.id %}">Place Order</a>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h5>Contact Information</h5>
            <hr>
            <p>Email: {{customer.email}}</p>
            <p>Phone: {{customer.phone}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h5>Total Order</h5>
            <hr>
            <h1 style="text-align: center;padding: 10px;">{{order_count}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <form method="POST">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Date Ordered</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>

                {% for order in orders %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{order.product}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.product.category}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.date_created}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.status}}</td>
                        <td><a  class="btn btn-outline-info btn-md " href="{% url 'update_order' order.id %}">Update</a></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-md " href="{% url 'delete_order' order.id %}">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**order_form.html**

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{formset.managment_form}} <!-- to remove the managmentForm data missing or has been tempered wiith , error -->
                {% for form in formset %}
                {{formset}}    <!--in context of views.py -->
                <hr>
                {% endfor %}

                <input class="btn btn-outline-success btn-md" type="submit" name="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I have added the templates , and thanks to all but I think the only problem is with urls.py , because if I use

```
path('create_order/<str:pk>/', views.createOrder, name="create_order"),
```

instead of

```
path('create_order', views.createOrder, name="create_order"),
```

then I get error, otherwise there is no such error for the above path.

Comment: Well that makes perfect sense, since if it has a parameter, you need to specify the value for the `pk` parameter, so `{% url 'create_order' pk=42 %}` for example.

Comment: {% url 'create_order ' customer.id %}
 already specified, the problem isn't in the html files, it's in the urls.py,  I don't know why it's not showing  the same error for other paths,as they have same  parameter

Comment: there still is at least one, note the "with **no** arguments" part in the error.

Comment: not working, checked

Comment: Share the template?

Comment: `{% url 'create_order' customer.id %}` - the view in your question does not have "customer" in the context so `customer.id` will return an empty string

Comment: sir I have added the templates in the question , but that's not the problem as I already have
 href="{% url 'create_order' customer.id %}"
in the customer.html

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the error.
So, error was here
the href which we have used id {% url 'create_order' customer.id %}

and this is in customer.html ,so the customer.id will get value provided by the views.customer
but if you see in your view.customer,
context = {'customers':customers,'orders': orders,'orders_count': orders_count}
because we followed a tutorial video, that guy did some changes which we didn't because it isn't shown in the video.

the changes he did was that
he changed 'customers' to 'customer' and now context of customer.html is good
because now it knows what the hell is customer.id

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the problem but just replaced the file urls.py from GitHub with the same context and it's not showing that error.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('products/', views.products, name='products'),
    path('customer/<str:pk_test>/', views.customer, name="customer"),

    path('create_order/<str:pk>/', views.createOrder, name="create_order"),
    path('update_order/<str:pk>/', views.updateOrder, name="update_order"),
    path('delete_order/<str:pk>/', views.deleteOrder, name="delete_order"),


]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
def createOrder(request, pk):
    OrderFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Customer, Order, fields=('product', 'status'), extra=10 )
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    formset = OrderFormSet(queryset=Order.objects.none(),instance=customer)
    #form = OrderForm(initial={'customer':customer})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print('Printing POST:', request.POST)
        #form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        formset = OrderFormSet(request.POST, instance=customer)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form':formset}
    return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html', context)
```

**order_form.html**

```
{%  extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-body">

            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.management_form }}
                {% for field in form %}
                    {{field}}
                    <hr>
                {% endfor %}

                <input type="submit" name="Submit">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Again I don't know why it was showing this error and where was the problem but just relapced it with the same code from GitHub and it worked.if someone know how it worked, that will be really helpful in near future.

Answer (score 1):

i know where the problem is

in the dashboard.html you should delete the line includes {% url 'create_order' %}

Answer (score 0):

in dashboard you should remove the line with create order
cause there is use of create_order url without id so there's an error